# Chef - ServerSpec - Accessing Node attributes

Tags: chef-infra, serverspec

I am in the process of writing ServerSpec tests for a cookbook I wrote. The tests need node attributes to assert various things through kitchen.

Fortunately, there is a guide here explaining how to achieve this:
http://jakshi.com/blog/2014/05/12/accessing-chef-attributes-in-serverspec-tests/

The problem I am having is, that this does not work:

```
attrs = attrs.deep_merge(node.override_attrs) unless node.override_attrs.empty?
```

But this works:

```
attrs = attrs.deep_merge(node.attributes.combined_override) unless node.attributes.combined_override.empty?
```

My setup is exactly same as described in the blog. Browsing [code](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/node.rb) did not help due to lack of ruby-fu. The chef-client version is 11.14.6 and Test-Kitchen version is 1.3.1

Can someone help please? Has anyone else had this problem? Thanks.

Update: Here are all the attributes from a dummy cookbook I created to simulate this.

```
cb-under-test/recipes/default.rb
<Nothing>


cb-under-test/test/fixtures/cookbooks/fake/attributes/default.rb
force_override['important_dir'] = 'test_recipe_force_override'


../env/dummy-env.json
{
  "name": "dummy-env",
  "description": "Dummy Env",
  "cookbook_versions": {
  },
  "json_class": "Chef::Environment",
  "chef_type": "environment",
  "override_attributes": {
    "important_dir": "env_override"
  }
}
```

Comment: Add the attribute file of your test cookbook, we can't guess at which level you set them...

Comment: The attributes come from several places including the environment. I do not have any attributes in my test cookbook.

Comment: Anyway, without an extract we can't guess at which levels your attributes are define (default, normal,  override, else ?)

Comment: Which version of chef are you using ? (Just to be sure which code I've to check over for the attributes levels accessors)

Comment: On the test VM it is 11.14.6. I am using chef solo through kitchen.

Comment: According to [the code](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/11.14.6/lib/chef/node/attribute.rb) there's no override_attrs method, here you'll have the cookbook's one under `node.override` and the env's one in `node.env_override`, the `node.combined_override` gives you the resulting attributes after deep merge. The blog post is quite old, you should better use `attrs = node.merged_attributes` to write the json file.

Comment: This makes so much sense and it works too! Thanks!
If you could put this in an answer I can accept.

Comment: You're right, I should have write it as an answer at first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the code](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/11.14.6/lib/chef/node/attribute.rb) there's no override_attrs method.

Here you'll have the cookbook's attributes under `node.override` and the environment's attributes in `node.env_override`, the `node.combined_override` gives you the resulting attributes after deep merge.

The blog post is quite old, you should better use `attrs = node.merged_attributes` to write the json file and get the resulting attributes from cookbook, roles and environments, using `merged_attributes` should avoid the `ohai` attributes to, keeping the json size low.

Comment: I was using a test_helper recipe which stored the node attributes in a file so ServerSpec could test against them, and found that the environment variables were not being merged in at all. Using `node.env_override` solved it for me. Thank you.